# mysqlimport cannot read trademark symbol

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I have a large CSV data file. One of the fields in the file contains ™ symbol. I have created the table using

```
CREATE TABLE scraped_data(
.....) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I have imported the data into the DB using mysqlimport command.

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-enclosed-by='"' --local -u root -p scraping scraped_data.csv
```

then, after processing I have exported the file back to csv. But the exported file contains `â„¢` symbol instead of ™. How do I retain this symbol in the exported csv ?

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 CHARSET?
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode.html]

Comment: As a note it's spelled "scraped". The word "scrapped" means something that's been discarded, like garbage.

Comment: The standard latin-1 codepage does not include the tm character. Only some localised versions may do so. Better to use utf8 or utf8mb4 character sets throughout the import and the export.

Comment: Surprisingly, MySQL's `latin1` is actually [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which does include ™. Chances are that your app is using Latin-1 it its real meaning (ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the charset to [`utf8`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) by creating table by using

```
CREATE TABLE scaped_data( 
....)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This solved the problem.